# Usar valor de variável como parâmetro em JS

Tags: javascript, html, string, funções, variáveis

Eu estava fazendo uns testes pra treinar JS com HTML. Aí fiz um sistema de boletim, onde um object boletim tem as notas de algumas matérias, e por um select escolhia a matéria e qual bimestre queria:

```js
var boletim = {matematica: [5.5, 10, 10, undefined], fisica: [5.1, 9.5, 10, undefined], ingles: [10, 10, 8.9, 10]}

function nota() {
    let res = document.querySelector("#res")
    let bim = Number(document.querySelector("#bim").value)
    let materia = document.querySelector("#materia").value
    res.innerHTML = `A nota no ${bim}º bimestre foi ${boletim.materia[bim - 1]}` 
}
```

A variável materia tem o valor do option escolhido pelo usuário, eu queria usar esse valor pra pegar um elemento do objeto boletim, como resolver isso?

Comment: Guilherme, por favor, coloca seu HTML também.

Comment: tente acessar o objeto boletim dessa forma boletim[materia][bim-1]

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel, deu certo. Obrigado por tentar também, Daniel Mendes